# how to make a unwindsegue to viewcontroller before a navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift3

i have a project where initial viewcontroller does not have a navigation controller a loguin windows after that  i have a navigatino controller to the main view. so when I tap on close session i make a segue to loguin windows but that does not destroy any windows opened in previous, so I google for a solution an i show a unwindsegue to main viewviewcontroller but always the initial view controller is behind a navigation controller so my real question is is a valid approach to make

```
@IBAction func unwindToVC1(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) { 
 self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goLogin", sender: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need change sender value nil to self value:

```
@IBAction func unwindToVC1(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) { 
  self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goLogin", sender: self)
}
```